# Terraform - Multiple "count" entries

Tags: terraform

I would like to create a resource if a certain value is "yes". And also create multiple resources when another variable is set to a number.

Using

```
count = "${var.create_vpc_resources == "yes" ? 1 : 0}"
```

Works to say if the resource is created or not. And `count = "${var.instance_numbers}"` works to create multiple resources.

How would I put these together on one line to say yes create the resource, and create a certain number of them.

Something like `count = "${var.is_windows_vm == "yes" ? 1 : 0}", "${var.instance_numbers}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to say something like the following

```
resource "my_resource" "name" {
  count = var.is_windows_vm === "yes" ? var.instance_numbers : 0
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. `count               =  var.is_windows_vm == "yes" ? var.instance_numbers : 0` worked! Cheers.